# Could not find com.google.gms:google-sevices:4.3.15. error in flutter android app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

trying to use flutter run to start application and get error:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.google.gms:google-sevices:4.3.15.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-sevices/4.3.15/google-sevices-4.3.15.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-sevices/4.3.15/google-sevices-4.3.15.pom
> - https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/com/google/gms/google-sevices/4.3.15/google-sevices-4.3.15.pom
> Required by:
> project :

Here are my gradle files:

app level:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "io.fireship.testapp.testapp"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "io.fireship.testapp.testapp"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    

}

apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-sevices:4.3.15'
```

Other Gradle File:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools'}
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-sevices:4.3.15'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Tried playing around with different versions, still no solutions

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the line :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-sevices:4.3.15'
```

from your app level build.gradle file (android/app/build.gradle).

That line should be in the project gradle file, and you already have it there.